# Flutter issue with Google Ads & Firebase Versions

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle, admob, adsense

I am using latest version of flutter 3.7.2
My app has google ads and firebase dependency for which is use following pubs latest versions

```
admob_flutter:
firebase_messaging:
firebase_core:
```

Everthing is working perfect but when I have uploaded app on playstore it gives me following error

[image]

For solution of above warning i done the change in app level gradle file and following line

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0' // this line added for solution
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

but after adding above line my firebase stopped working it crash when run app with following error[image].

> NOTE: I have tried flutter clean, reinstall app, flutter pub upgrade
> everything is up-to date.  Also when i change line implementation
> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0' to implementation
> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0' everything is
> working perfect

Answer (score 1):

you help me with the part that you say works with only  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0' and I had the same problem but trying to solve it by changing this line:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.5.0'
}
```

you try to change firebase-ads:19.1.0 to 21.5.0 and it will let you use
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'

It works for me, hope helps you.

Comment: I try more and if you are using admob_flutter: ^3.0.0 changing to 21.5.0 you will get into trouble because the admob class isn't updated. You can try.

Comment: Not working for me I tried

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **'admob_flutter'** and update to  **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:2.50.0'** you couldn't use Admob, this is because **'admob_flutter'** does not support 'play-services-ads:2.50.0'.

In this case, I used **'google_mobile_ads 2.3.0'** it's verified and published by 'google.dev

https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads